# How to write right query using QueryBuilder

Tags: sql, typeorm, query-builder

I am trying to create QueryBuilder query but all the time failing.
I need to write query like this:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*) votes from uservotes WHERE sessionId = ? GROUP BY userId
```

but using QueryBuilder
All that I done and somehow work it is this variant.

```
.createQueryBuilder('uservotes')
    .select([
        'uservotes.userId', 'userId',
    ])
    .where({ sessionId: sessionId })
    .groupBy('userId')
    .getMany();
```

Will be very grateful for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
const countByUserVotes = await Uservotes.createQueryBuilder()
        .select(['userId', 'count(*) as count'])
        .where({ sessionId: sessionId })
        .groupBy('userId')
        .getRawMany();
```

Comment: @Volodymur happy to help